# using find's -path and -prune options

Tags: find

I want to find files in the `/tmp` directory. I use `-path` and `-prune` to exclude the subdirectory `sgid` from the results.

So I do something like this:

```
[root@ tmp]# find ./ -path ./sgid -prune -o -name 'foo*'
./sgid
./foo1
./dir1/foo2
./sgid0/foo1
./sgid0/foo
./sgid0/foo2
```

However the output still contains the `sgid` subdirectory, which is not what I expect.

But when i do like the following：

```
[root@ tmp]# find ./ -path ./sgid -prune -o -name 'foo*' -print
./foo1
./dir1/foo2
./sgid0/foo1
./sgid0/foo
./sgid0/foo2
```

The output matches my expectation. Why does the command have to include the `-print` option?